# Sum values up to certain value by date then start over

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying to sum values up to a certain limitation and if it reaches or exceeds the value, it will start summing over again.

I am needing to sum the number of TimesCalled and if the DaysBetweenCalls exceeds the DaysBetweenCallsLimit, the sum would start over.

In this example, I would sum the first 3 lines in the timescalled (20 + 2 + 15 = 37) because the "DaysBetweenCalls" (0+1+27= 28) is less than the "DaysBetweenCallsLimit" (30). Since the last record occurs after 30 days have been reached, the sum starts over again.
I would like to return results that look like this with SQL calculating the "Call Accum" Column which performs the task mentioned above.

| Name | Loc | DateCalled | TimesCalled | DaysBtwnCalls | DaysBtwnCallsLimit | CallAccum |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Sharon | NY | 5/27/2020 | 20 | 0 | 30 | 20 |
| Sharon | NY | 5/28/2020 | 2 | 1 | 30 | 22 |
| Sharon | NY | 6/24/2020 | 15 | 27 | 30 | 37 |
| Sharon | NY | 7/7/2020 | 15 | 13 | 30 | 15 |

I would be so grateful for any help you can provide.

Here is what I am trying, but as you can see this will only accumulate one row preceding and sometimes I need more than 1 row to reach the limitation.

```
SELECT Name, Loc, DateCalled, TimesCalled, DaysBtwnCalls,DaysBtwnCallsLimit,
Sum(DaysBtwnCalls) Over (Partition by Name, Loc Order By DateCalled ROWS BETWEEN 1 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) as CallAccum
from WRK_ACCUM A left join wrk_accum2 b on a.row2 = b.ROW#  
ORDER BY NAME, LOC
```

Comment: can you a tag for the database you are using?

Comment: @nbk yes absolutely- I just added the script I am using to the comment :) Thanks so much for looking at this.

Comment: that is very old so you should urgently update it

Comment: Sql Server supports recursive CTE  since 2005.

Comment: @nbk It is a work SQL server that is shared across the org. We definitely need something better.